# Running an O/S script from DBMS_SCHEDULER

Tags: oracle

Have a need to run an O/S bash script from an Oracle 19.6 database.

Here is my test case on my test database:

I want it to write out to a file, but right now I can't even get the job to run.

```
SQL> host cat test.sh
source /home/oracle/.bashrc

# /bin/echo "TEST SCRIPT!" > test_script.out
/bin/echo “Job ok!”;

SQL> host /home/oracle/sql/test.sh
“Job ok!”
```

Result

```
  STATUS     ADDITIONAL_INFO
---------- -----------------------------------------------------
FAILED     EXTERNAL_LOG_ID="job_293887_405260",
           ORA-27369: job of type EXECUTABLE failed with exit co
           de: No such file or directory
```

HOWEVER, I've given it the whole path and creds with the secret password

```
SQL> host ls /home/oracle/sql/test.sh
/home/oracle/sql/test.sh




program_type        => 'EXTERNAL_SCRIPT',
program_action      => '/home/oracle/sql/test.sh',
number_of_arguments => 0,
enabled             => TRUE,



  dbms_credential.create_credential(
    credential_name => 'ORACLE_CRED',
    username        => 'oracle',

DBMS_SCHEDULER.SET_ATTRIBUTE (
name => 'TEST_EXECUTABLE',
attribute => 'credential_name',
value => 'ORACLE_CRED');
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Is your sqlplus session run on the database server?

Comment: @Fat P Yes it is

Answer (score 0):

You're missing the OS access permissions for the `oracle` OS account.

Make sure the OS user `oracle` can run it before trying to run it from `DBMS_SCHEDULER`.

(Adjust account name according to the `username => 'xxx'` settings)

Comment: $ id
uid=54321(oracle) gid=54321(oinstall) 
-rwxr-xr-x 1 oracle oinstall 99 May 11 12:57 ./test.sh
oracle@test:(cdb1)~/sql$ ./test.sh
“Job ok!”

Comment: As oracle O/S use I can run it.